# How to asynchronously move multiple overlayed images using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 10 shapes that collectively define a square image as shown below. I would like to move each image using the output of a periodic function like *sine* that takes user mouse position as an input. Each image should have a different frequency and period affecting it's motion so that as a user mouses over the scene the shapes jitter past each other.

[image]

So far I've managed to get 1 shape to move using this:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
        var track = function(ampl, freq) {
        return {
            x   : ampl * Math.sin(freq*e.pageX),
            y   : ampl*1.6 * Math.sin(freq*e.pageY)
        };
    }

        var current = track(10, 0.05);
    $("#image").css({left:current.x, top:current.y});

});
```

How can I get [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/2941/) to do that for the other 9 shapes?

Comment: All these answer's are way better than [this which I just made and knew could be done better](http://jsfiddle.net/pkv79eyg/2/). I'll review and  select an answer shortly. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/jfhk8bye/

```
track = function(ampl, freq, pageX, pageY) {
    return {
        x   : ampl * Math.sin(freq*pageX),
        y   : ampl*1.6 * Math.sin(freq*pageY)
    };
}
$imgs = $('img.image')
$(document).mousemove(function(e)
{
    $imgs.each(function()
  {
    var $img = $(this);
    var current = track($img.data('ampl'), $img.data('freq'), e.pageX, e.pageY);
    console.log(current);
    $img.css({left:current.x, top:current.y});
  });
});
```

What I did:

- Qualified image IDs into classes instead (updating CSS too)
- Added data attributes to the image elements representing their frequencies and amplitudes (this way you can control these values in HTML)
- Updated your javascript appropriately and optimised it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g7Lpnw5b/

Replace your `id`'s with class names, as multiple elements cannot share the same name, then iterate over the elements to move them each to different coordinates. You may want to tweak the parameters of the `track` function to have the shapes move as you like.

Answer (score 1):

What @charsi said is true.

You also need to use `$.each(index,el)` to get a different index value and use it in the `sin` `cos` function.

### [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/BfLAh/2945/)

```
function track(ampl, freq, index,x,y) {
  return {
    x   : ampl * Math.sin(freq*x + index),
    y   : ampl*1.6 * Math.sin(freq*y + index)
  };
}

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $(".image").each(function(index,el){
           var current = track(5, 0.05, index, e.pageX, e.pageY);
       $(this).css({left:current.x, top:current.y});
    });
});
```

***Updated: The function should be outside the `mousemove` event***

Answer (score 0):

Because all images haves the same id and jquery is only expecting one. It is applying the change to the first one it finds. Give each one a different id and add them to the list. Also change the value of current before each one if you dont want them to align.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to do that. I knew that was at play and have tried renaming my labels only to find that then nothing moves to mouse input.